# Migrating from sorcery to devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, sorcery

I have a project that, as the title suggests, is currently on the authentication library sorcery. I would like to migrate the user database to devise, because the client's developer wants to use it.

I understand that both libraries use similar encryption methods, but am not sure of the steps.

Currently on rails latest version.

Comment: were you able to figure this out?